# MYSQL count the number of times value is in 2 different columns

Tags: mysql

I have a database that contains Call Detail Records.  I would like to run a query that will return the total number of calls by the phone number. Each row in the database represents a single phone call.    The call could either be one that was placed by the number represented by the column `callingPartyNumber` or one that was placed to the number represented by the column `finalCalledPartyNumber`.

For example lets say phone number 5555551212 placed 3 calls and received 2 calls. The result of the query should return the phone number and total number of calls (5555551212, 5)

I've tried a few different queries based on other questions i've found on stackoverflow including:

```
    SELECT callingPartyNumber, COUNT(*) as count FROM CDR 
    GROUP BY finalCalledPartyNumber HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

and

```
    SELECT id, callingPartyNumber, finalCalledPartyNumber, count(*) AS count
    FROM CDR
    GROUP BY callingPartyNumber, finalCalledPartyNumber
```

However im not getting back the expected results.  Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `UNION` of two queries for each type of call and then `GROUP BY` the temporary result by phone number:

```
SELECT All_Numbers.number, SUM(count) AS total_count
FROM (
    SELECT callingPartyNumber AS number, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM CDR
    GROUP BY callingPartyNumber
    UNION
    SELECT finalCalledPartyNumber AS number, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM CDR
    GROUP BY finalCalledPartyNumber
) AS All_Numbers
GROUP BY All_Numbers.number
```

This assumes that no number can call itself, which would lead to double-counting in the solution I gave above.

Comment: Very nice. Runs quickly too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I was having issues with SUM(*) giving me the old #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax.  I changed it to SUM(count) and its working great!